# How Does VideoToolbox.framework work?

Tags: ios, xcode

iOS8 just released beta version, I'm very interested in Video directly Encoding / Decoding.

> **Video Toolbox Framework**
>
> The Video Toolbox framework (VideoToolbox.framework) includes direct
>   access to hardware video encoding and decoding.

but I can not find any tutorial documents for this right now

as I know it's a private framework before, and some people already using it in some JB apps

so does anyone can share a very simple tutorial code for this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Import the framework and look at the headers, they're all documented.

Apple also released a [sample using VTDecompressionSession](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/samplecode/VideoTimeline/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014525)

Comment: you just save my ass !!

Comment: the link is dead now.

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/wwdc/resources/sample-code/ has a link to it at the bottom.

Comment: Neither link works for VTDecompressionSession sample code.

Answer (score 15):

1. Try this link: https://github.com/davidliu/VideoTimeLine  (the video which I loaded seems to be broken, but you can get a feel how to use it).
2. Write in XCode: `import VideoToolbox` and `CMVideoFormatDescriptionCreateFromH264ParameterSets` and Cmd+click on it to display documentation :)
3. Take a look at this video from WWDC: https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2014/#513
4. Check out this code: https://github.com/manishganvir/iOS-h264Hw-Toolbox
5. Check out this code: https://github.com/McZonk/VideoToolboxPlus
6. You might also want to see a detailed description on how to decompress H264 using VideoToolbox: [How to use VideoToolbox to decompress H.264 video stream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29525000/how-to-use-videotoolbox-to-decompress-h-264-video-stream)

Hope that helps :)